# Update someones birthday with javascript

Tags: javascript

So far the only mathematical way I can think of doing it is this:

```
var age = 18
var today = new Date();

var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2013,3,13); /* My birthday is april 13th */

var y = (today - myDate);

var days = ( y / (1000*60*60*24));

if(days >= 360){
    var age = age +1;
}

if(days >= 720){
    var age = age +1;
}

//etc......
document.write(age);
```

Is there a better way of doing the **if** statements? so that I don't have to write one out for every year? I can't think!

Comment: Um...365 days in most years...

Comment: Haaa My bad! That is very embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:-

```
var age = 18
var today = new Date();

var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2013,3,13); /* My birthday is april 13th */

var y = (today - myDate);

var days =  ( y / (1000*60*60*24));

var x= Math.floor(days/365.25);

var age = age +x;

document.write( age);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all your days trick can easily be done like this:

```
age += Math.floor(days/360); // should be 365 imho
```

Second of all, you don't need to get the days to convert to years (which is broken at the edges beacuse of leap years), but instead you can use the getYear method:

```
var age = 18
var today = new Date();

var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2013,3,13); /* My birthday is april 13th */

var age += today.getYear() - myDate.getYear();
// adjust for months and days
if (today.getMonth() < myDate.getMonth() || 
    today.getMonth() == myDate.getMonth()  && today.getDay() < myDate.getDay())
     age--;

document.write(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to write algorithms that can handle leap years, leap centuries, and leap seconds, I'd advise using built-in methods of the Date class and/or libraries to help you figure out whether a year has 365 or 366 days. Most years don't have 360 days in them.

Comment: `<pedant mode>`Could you mention **one** that does `</pedant mode>` have 360 days? :p

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Haha! Got me there, nice.:) Even better when it comes from someone I assume to be a fellow aussie!